# How to add a "please wait" text message into pace loader

Tags: loader, pace

I'm using Pace loader (http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) and I use the "flash" preload theme. Now, I put the small circular preloader in the left side of the screen .I have added also a div with a class called "cover". This div cover all the page and disappear with fade effect when the page is loaded. All work perfectly.

Now, I would like to add a small text message in the right of the circular preload, "loading, please wait..." for example ([`see pic 1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiAG9.jpg)).

Here my pace.css:

```css
    .cover { 
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transform: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transform: opacity 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transform: opacity 0.5s ease;
         transform: opacity 0.5s ease;
}


body.pace-running .cover {
    opacity: 0;
}


body.pace-done .cover {
    opacity: 1;
}


.pace {
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -50px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50px, 0);

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}

.pace.pace-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.pace-running .cover{
    zoom:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=10);
    opacity:1;
}
.pace-done .cover{
    zoom:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s linear;
    transition:opacity 1s linear;
}




.pace {
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.pace-inactive {
  display: none;
}

.pace .pace-progress {
  background: #142126;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
}

.pace .pace-progress-inner {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: ;
  opacity: 1.0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
  transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
}

.pace .pace-activity {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  border-top-color: #142126;
  border-left-color: #142126;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Colud someone help me to reach this goal? I try to manipulate the css, but nothing. Thanks for answer me.

Answer (score 0):

just resolve the issue. I've added this few lines of code into css, hope it can help someone out there ;-)

```
  .pace:after {
  content: "LOADING CONTENT...PLEASE WAIT";
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', ;
  font-size:14px;
  margin-top:18px;
  color:#464652;
  position:absolute;
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  letter-spacing:0.8px;
  font-weight:400;
  }
```